# How to solve $ x * 23 \equiv_{60} 1 $ with $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ x > 100$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can somebody help me how to solve

$x* 23 \equiv_{60} 1 $ with $ x \in \mathbb{N} $ and $x > 100$

What would be a good approach?

I know that x = 107 would be a solution. However how can I find solutions and how to prove that there are no solutions, if there aren't any?

Comment: What do you mean by $x\cdot 23 \equiv_{60} 1$? Is it $x\cdot 23 \equiv 1 \pmod{60}$?

Comment: Yes x*23 mod 60 = 1

Comment: see [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Mathematical_applications) for the procedure to follow to identify $y$ such that $(23y) \equiv 1 \pmod{60}.$  Given any satisfying value $y$, then all numbers of the form $(y + 60t)$ will also be satisfactory, where $t$ is any positive or negative integer.

Comment: This is the approach we used in school. however I hoped there is a shortcut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) tells you that for $n$ and $a$ coprime, you have $$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \bmod n$$ where $\phi(n)$ is [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) which counts the numbers less than $n$ and coprime to it.

So in this case we would know that $$23^{\phi(60)} = 23^{16} \equiv 1 \bmod 60$$ so we can say that $$x\equiv 23^{15} \bmod 60 $$ gives us solutions.

There is also [Carmichael's reduced totient function $\lambda$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) which often gives a smaller exponent for the same purpose. In this case $\lambda(60) = 4$ and so we can use $x\equiv 23^{\lambda(60)-1}\equiv 23^3 \equiv 47 \bmod 60$.

Now this gives your value, since $107\equiv 47\bmod 60$, and is one of the possible choice of the integers $47+60k$ which obey the equivalence.

---

For a rapid method not using exponents, the extended Euclidean algorithm will both check that $a$ and $n$ are coprime and deliver the modular inverse of $a\bmod m$ (which is what your equation here is asking for, $ax\equiv 1 \bmod n$). Note that solving this also helps to solve other $\bmod n$ equations involving $a$.

Answer (score 1):

$x\cdot a\equiv_{b} 1\implies x=\frac{-(b^{-1})\cdot b+1}{a}\bmod b$

Comment: What is b^-1 ? also how to derive this formula?

Comment: The multiplicative inverse of $b$ modulo $a$  . You note that   the additive inverse of the multiplicative inverse returns the value  -1 when multiplied.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Euclidean algorithm.

Since $\gcd(23,60) = 1$ there exists integers $m,n$ such that $23m + 60n = 1.$

$m$ will be our inverse.

The Euclidean algorithm:

$\begin {array}{rrc}
n&m&60n+23m\\ \hline
1&&60\\
&1&23\\ 
1&-2&14\\
-1&3&9\\
2&-5&5\\
5&-13&1\\
\end{array}$

What are we doing?  The first column are candidates for $n.$  The second column are candidates for $m.$  The third column is $60n + 23m.$

We then subtract the largest multiple in the lines below from lines above to generate smaller numbers for $60n + 23m.$

We get down to $-13$ as a multiplicative inverse.  And if $-13$ is an inverse, so is $47.$

Comment: Thanks..But shouldn't it be -13 instead of -17? Euclid gives me bezout coefficients of 5, -13..also -13 mod 60 = 47